How to invoke action and func and return value in a single method
I have a method called GetBalance to call an API. Before calling GetBalance I need to get access token. Unfortunately, the token expired in few minutes. All I want here is if I call an endpoint and gives me expired token response it will automatically get access token.
Normally, I can do like this
await GetAccessToken()
CreateSignature(uri, body);
return await httpClient.PostJson<Balance>(uri, body); //PostJson is extension method

So, I don't need to check the response to check if the token expired.
var result = await httpClient.PostJson<Balance>(uri, body);
if (result.Message == ""Token Expired")
{
    await GetAccessToken();
    result = await httpClient.PostJson<Balance>(uri, body);
}

return result;

I want to invoke Action and Func in single method as follows.
private async Task<T> InvokeMethodRefreshToken<T>(Action createSignature, Func<Task<T>> func)
{
    var result = await func.Invoke();
    if (result != null)
    {
        var msg = (result as BaseResponse).Message;
        if (msg == "Token Expired")
        {
            var token = await GetAccessToken();
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(token.AccessToken))
            {
                createSignature.Invoke();
                result = await func.Invoke();
            }
            else
            {
                result = (T)token.Copy(result.GetType());
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}

private async Task<Token> GetAccessToken()
{
    //set http header with bearer token
}

private void CreateSignature(string uri, object body)
{
    //create signature and set http header
}

private async Task<Balance> GetBalance()
{
    string uri = "/user/balance";
    var body = new 
    {
        phoneAccount = "xxx"
    };
    
    //How to..
    return await InvokeMethodRefreshToken(() => 
        CreateSignatureSymetric(uri, q, trxId), 
        client.PostAsJsonAsync<BalanceResponse>(uri, q)
    );
}

I cannot call CreateSignature directly from InvokeMethodRefreshToken because some parameters change.

Are you looking for InvokeMethodRefreshToken(() => CreateSignatureSymetric(uri, q, trxId), () => client.PostAsJsonAsync<BalanceResponse>(uri, q))? It's a little unclear what your question is.

Yes, exactly @canton7 . Make it as answer and I'll accept it

I've linked your question to a similar one about how to pass lambdas as method parameters. I don't think we need another question about a basic bit of C# syntax, particularly when the actual question is quite convoluted and unlikely to be applicable to others
